# Keep an SKNode from leaving the view

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am working on a "Space Invaders" game, I have implemented  CMMotionManager to move my heroShip on tilt(the game only runs in landscape), but for some reason my ship will move out of the view even though

```
self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
```

should have prevented this by making a physics edge. Any ideas why?

```
   import SpriteKit
    import CoreMotion

class GameScene: SKScene,SKPhysicsContactDelegate{
    let collisionBulletCategory: UInt32  = 0x1 << 0
    let collisionHeroCategory: UInt32    = 0x1 << 1
    let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background")
    let heroShip = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "heroShip")
    let enemyShip = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "enemyShip")
    let MotionManager = CMMotionManager()



    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */
        self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

        self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
        background.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        heroShip.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 0.5)
        heroShip.physicsBody?.mass = 0.02
        heroShip.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        heroShip.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: heroShip.size)
        heroShip.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        heroShip.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = collisionHeroCategory
        heroShip.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = collisionBulletCategory
        heroShip.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0x0
        heroShip.position =  CGPointMake(self.size.width/6.0, self.size.height/2.0)
        enemyShip.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        enemyShip.zPosition = 1.0
        self.heroShip.zPosition = 1.0
        self.addChild(enemyShip)
        self.addChild(background)
        self.addChild(heroShip)

        if MotionManager.accelerometerAvailable{
            MotionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates()
        }

    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        let bullet = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bullet")
        bullet.position = CGPointMake(heroShip.position.x, heroShip.position.y)
        bullet.zPosition = 1.0
        // Add physics body for collision detection
        bullet.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: bullet.frame.size)
        bullet.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        bullet.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        bullet.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = collisionBulletCategory
        bullet.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = collisionHeroCategory
        bullet.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0x0;
        let action = SKAction.moveToX(CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame) + bullet.size.width, duration: 0.75)
        self.addChild(bullet)
        bullet.runAction(action, completion: {
            bullet.removeAllActions()
            bullet.removeFromParent()
        })
    }

    func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    }
    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        let data = MotionManager.accelerometerData
        if data?.acceleration.x == nil{
            print("nil")
        }
        else if fabs((data?.acceleration.x)!) > 0.2 {
            self.heroShip.physicsBody?.applyForce(CGVectorMake(0.0, CGFloat(50 * (data?.acceleration.x)!)))

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the docs, this is how collision happen:

> When two physics bodies contact each other, a collision may occur.
>   This body’s collision mask is compared to the other body’s category
>   mask by performing a logical AND operation. If the result is a nonzero
>   value, this body is affected by the collision. Each body independently
>   chooses whether it wants to be affected by the other body. For
>   example, you might use this to avoid collision calculations that would
>   make negligible changes to a body’s velocity.

You have set player's collisionBitMask to something like `0x00000000` (all bits cleared). By default a categoryBitMask is set to `0xFFFFFFFF` (all bits set). Because you haven't stated otherwise, scene's physics body categoryBitMask is set to `0xFFFFFFFF`. When logical AND (&) operator is performed between those two, a result will be zero, means no collision.

To fix this, you can just remove this line:

```
 heroShip.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0x0
```

Or set it properly by defining a Wall category...

**HINTS:**

- Anchor point defines how texture is drawn relative to the node's position. It has nothing with physics body. Physics body, by default is centered to the node's position. If you turn-on physics visual representation (`skView.showsPhysics = true`) you will see, in your example, that physics body is not positioned as it should.
- Setting up physics body before you have actually initialized it  make no sense. You have to initialize physics body first.

Comment: This is correct, I just had the 0x0 and didn't have a sceneCategory UInt32 set up yet. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Whirlwind's answer, you probably also want to enable `usesPreciseCollisionDetection` on your physics body.  By setting this to  `true`, this will prevent your `heroShip` from popping through the wall if it encounters a massive force from the accelerometer data.

Basically, the physics is calculated as where it is going to be.  So if there is a massive force, it could say, "Oh, this massive force means I should be way over here outside the bounding box."  If you have precise collision detection enabled, this will force it to calculate physics for multiple positions from the start position of this frame, to the calculated position.  If it hits something before getting to the calculated position, then it adjusts so that it doesn't go through whatever it hit.  For the most part, you don't have to worry about this, but it is better to be safe than sorry.

So put this line somewhere in your physics body configuration code after initialization of it:

```
heroShip.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
```